# Python AES Decrypt printed with encrypted text

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes

i got a problem with decryption text file that say 'i want to be clear text file'.

the encryption is good work but when i decrypt it's get mixed, clear text and encrypt data.

now i know me writing is a little amateurish.. but i need your help to get it through.
i tried to build it in def functions but it didn't went well..

I'm thinking that the padding in the encryption is the problem, but when i test it on a 16 byte text file it's still was mixed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto import Random
import os

file_path = raw_input("Enter File path: ")
if os.path.isdir(file_path):  #check if the path exists
    print "\nFile path founded, continue..\n"
else:
    print "\nFile path is not correct\nExiting.\n"
    exit(0)
file_name = raw_input("Enter File name: ")
full_path =  file_path + file_name
if os.path.isfile(full_path):
    print "\nFile name founded, continue..\n"
else:
    print "\nFile name is not correct\nExiting.\n"
    exit(0)



print "Now encrypt"
key_size = 32 #AES256
iterations = 10000
key = os.urandom(32)
read = open(full_path,'r+')
line = read.readline()
secret = line
length = 16 - (len(secret) % 16) #PKCS7 adds bytes of the length of padding
secret += chr(length) * length
read.close()
salt = Random.new().read(key_size) #salt the hash
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
derived_key = PBKDF2(key, salt, key_size, iterations)
cipher = AES.new(derived_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

encodedtext = iv + cipher.encrypt(secret)
read = open(full_path, 'w')
read.write(encodedtext)
read.close()


print "Now decrypt"
key_size2 = 32 #AES256
iterations2 = 10000
read2 = open(full_path,'r')
line2 = read2.readline()
secret2 = line2
length2 = 16 - (len(secret2) % 16) #PKCS7 adds bytes of the length of padding
secret2 += chr(length2) * length2
read2.close()
dencodedtext2 = iv + cipher.decrypt(secret2)
read2 = open(full_path, 'w')
read2.write(dencodedtext2)
read2.close()
print "that worked?"
```

for the test
i gave a path '/home/****/Dekstop/
and i gave file 'test.txt' with the text 'i want to be clear text file'
and i got this,

> 悑晍㱣໸弧殲턕컫聅㇛좎䀋傖粁﻿i want to be clear text fileԊԅԅᡶ䴈ᚖ↺髱준Ⴕꂛ

why when i print secret2 after 'dencodedtext2 = iv + cipher.decrypt(secret2)' the text is mixed with encryption?
how can i fixed it?
and what im doing so terrible?

thank a head for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1):

There are two major mistakes within the code:

- the IV needs to be stripped off before (and used during) decryption instead of adding it again to the plaintext; currently your plaintext starts with the IV and then a decrypted IV;
- the padding needs to be removed after decryption, not before, currently some padding related muck is still shown at the end.

Comment: how do i stripped off the IV **before** decryption?
as much then i can see i remove the padding before the decryption.
any case of example?

Comment: I'm not sure I want to make that effort, especially since the code you've provided doesn't show much effort with regards to *problem decomposition*, i.e. splitting the functionality in separate problems and therefore methods. Besides, we're talking about splitting an array and removing bytes from the right of an array here. That's not rocket science, right? There should be plenty of examples around.